# Select in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the following database scheme:

[image]

And the problem is the next:

What are the names of subjects which has been examined by teacher with the code 0009?

So, I select the Subject_IDs from Exam which are taught by teacher 0009, but after that how can I output the Name of the subjects from Subjects table if the Subject_ID equals the result from the first select?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your plan on how to arrive at the solution? What obstacles do you encounter?  Hint: Find all the places the information you are looking for can be seen in your schema diagram. Finally just a benevolent advice, not meant to offend you: Shrink-wrapped solution may come handy short-term, but your question is fairly elementary, you should at least understand the solution in detail ... otherwise dbs will not be your friends ( and if they do not need to be, you might wish to reconsider your training/courses/career )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT S.Name 
  FROM Subjects S 
 WHERE S.Subject_id IN (SELECT E.Subject_id 
                          FROM Exams E 
                         WHERE E.Teacher_id='0009')
```